# DocumentDB and Lambda, connection errors

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-documentdb

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/connect.html

I am using the above code in my lambda node.js code, which is deployed via serverless framework. I have written my own code via mongoose library but that didn't work, then I decided to use the code from AWS documentation but even that didn't work.

What I have done so far:

- DocDB instance and Lambda function are in same VPC
- Tried to turn TLS on and off (used the certificate for TLS, did everything as documentation describes)
- I have allowed 27017 port to every direction (both outbound and inbound, to be sure) and even allowed all traffic for all ports and protocols (yes that's a bad practice, but was trying to find the root of issue)
- Tried mongoose or vanilla mongo driver for node.js (with both latest and downgraded versions)
- I can connect to the instance if I create an EC2 instance within the same VPC, and use mongoshell via SSH. But lambda can't connect.
- Tried to increase socketTimeoutMS, poolSize and reconnectTries.
- Even tried to deploy my whole project on another region.

Any of above didn't help. The error I am getting constantly is:

```
2019-11-20T13:44:34.282Z    57cba251-15aa-4c3d-8601-f5c7e9270b66    INFO    { MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [****.****.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connection 0 to ****.****.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017 timed out]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:562:11)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:316:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:256:10)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:443:8)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  message:
   'failed to connect to server [****.****.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connection 0 to ****.****.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017 timed out]',
  errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

Additionally, I was getting "server selection timed out after 30000ms" error before but that disappeared when I removed /dbname from the connection URI.

In the first request, I get no console output (which exists in aws doc code) but when I do a second request it returns me the error. I have seen some connections in docDB metrics but I supposed to have a console output if a connection was successful?

My best guess is the connection is dropped by firewall on security group but I am sure I allowed the ports on security group page and the groups and VPCs are set correctly. I have done the same for an RDS instance (it was a similiar issue) and it was resolved but it isn't this time.

My connection URI is basically: mongodb://username:pwd@**.**.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017When I add /dbname to the end of string, I get server selection timed out error..

I can't find the root of the problem.In the internet people mostly talk about being in same VPC, security groups or mongo client bugs.

As you can see from the list above, I tried all of them.I am really desperate for any ideas.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: can you check whether the Lambda function is in the same VPC as the DocDB cluster? Also would be worth checking whether the security group has the appropriate inbound and outbound rules

Comment: I am running into the same problem. I have even created the IAM roleName and put it into the serverless.yml.

however, after deploy the lambda still not in the same VPC. Even I set the VPC of the lambda function manually, it still wont' work. :(

have you resolve it?

Comment: here is what my problem was resolved.  when I SLS deploy using the express serverless yml, it creates the Lambda without VPC. so when I add the VPC in manually, I have to also fix the api gateway to point to the latest version of lambda function, not the default one.  then problem solved.

Comment: i think @meet-bhagdev is right. DocumentDb works in VPC but lambda doesnt. So, you need to configure your serverless.yaml file for use VPC in lambda.